# JDBC connection pooling issue

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have, I might say, a quite a big issue.

I'm working on Java web application which use springs BasicDataSource to setup DB connection. I was testing the application locally and it works just fine... but, when application is online, connection to DB in some point just stuck. I was than investigating regarding connection pooling, and I figure it out that on each new HTTP request, where I have some of the queries executed, new pool is created. As I know, pooling is introduced to be reusable, and not created the each time when new DB access is involved. Or I'm wrong?

Here is my spring datasource config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="url"/>
        <property name="username" value="username"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
 <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="1"/>
 <property name="initialSize" value="0"/>
 <property name="maxActive" value="20"/>
 <property name="minIdle" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

Than I have configured:

```
<bean id="EventDao" class="my.managament.database.class">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

And mainPageController which handles all HTTP requests sent to application

```
<bean id="mainController" class="my.management.main.controller.class">
```

In the rest of application, I use gedDatabase() to acquire DB connection, and do select through JDBCTemplate.

Where am I getting wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to state that a new connection is getting created, instead of stating that a new connection pool is getting created on every request. If not, this is indeed a big problem. May I suggest that you edit the question to include why you believe that the pool is getting recreated every request.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I was clear... What I tried to do is to create only one connection, with consideration that new pools are going to be created, but also reused... not on each single request to create new one... in 1000 requests, I have dozen thousands of pools invoked.

Comment: If it is of any help, I've implemented this much like described in tutorial here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringJDBC/article.html

I hope someone had the same problem and managed to fix it... or if someone have tutorials which show the right way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use dao and jdbcTemplate and dataSource through a connection pool. My guess the closest correct approach to your setup is having a dao which has JdbcTemplate field and a JdbcTemplate bean created with your dataSource bean. It would look like:

```
public class MyDAO {
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  // your dao methods using jdbcTemplate here
}
```

where jdbcTemplate comes from a bean like:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <constructor-arg ref="dataSource">
</bean>
```

You should never need to obtain a connection from dataSource (which is apache dbcp based connection pool in your case) directly. JdbcTemplate will get a connection itself when needed. I'm not sure what "gedDatabase" is but it sounds like you tried to get connection yourself and possibly forgot to close it. This would result in pool quickly running out of connections. After handling 20 requests, the subsequent requests would be stuck on attempt to get connection from the pool.

Also I don't understand why and how you see multiple pools. You have a single connection pool which can hold up to 20 connections. All your beans are created as singletons which is the default spring scope.

Comment: I just noticed that I haven't copied all the necessary config., and it is not gedDatabase, it's getDatabase() :)... mainController uses setter dependency injection, and sets dataSource previously initialized by EventDao. EventDao is instanced only once!

Comment: My main concern was what is getDatabase doing and how often do you call it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the life time of your EventDao ? You are injecting your DataSource into the dataSource property. I suspect that you are creating multiple EventDao beans and each time you create one you have a new DataSource. I think we would need to have further understanding of the code to be able to answer your question properly.

My two cents:
As far as I am concerned having code and wiring things through XML is a terrible anti-pattern.